# Typescript named function expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, backend

I'm starting to learning typescript applied to node JS backend.
For now i'm still using function and not class.
I used to write named function for each file like

```
const item= {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    function1:()=>{
       console.log(item.a)
    },
    function2:()=>{
       console.log(item.b)
    } }
```

then  export it and use like item.function1. (i sometimes use it also as function1 with import as unstructured object)

Now using typescript i'm still using this approach but with types. The problem is that i can't assign a type to a because it's seen as value. I can't heither do :

```
const item= {
function1:()=>{
    item.a = 3
    console.log(item.a)
},
function2:()=>{
    item.b = 4
    console.log(item.b)
}}
```

because it's saying that property a or b does not exist in type item.
another thing i tried but that doesn't work is:

```
const item = {
function1:()=>{
    item.a:number = 3
    console.log(item.a)
},
function2:()=>{
    item.b:number = 4
    console.log(item.b)
} }
```

Anyone can help me? hoping that this named functions are not a bad habit for write code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable and don't specify its type, typescript will try to infer what its type is. When you assign an object, it will try to infer the type like this: look at what properties you wrote and consider that the object only has these properties with exactly the types that the object you wrote has. So in your last code example typescript will infer that `item` is of type

```
const item: {
  function1: () => void
  function2: () => void
} = {
// ...
}
```

You can see that it didn't add any other properties.

Next, if you don't declare a property when typing an object, typescript will think that this property doesn't exist and may not exist on the object. Consider this:

```
const obj: { foo: number } = {
  foo: 6
}

obj.bar = 7 // Error
```

You didn't declare the `bar` property, so typescript doesn't allow to read it or assign something to it. This is why you cannot write `item.a = 3` in your example: typescript didn't infer that `item` object has property `a` and it thinks that it must not exist

To solve this you just need to either assign all properties you will need when creating your object:

```
const item = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  function1: () => { /* ... */ },
  function2: () => { /* ... */ },
}
```

Or type `item` manually

```
interface Item {
  a?: number
  b?: number
  function1: () => void
  function2: () => void
}

const item: Item = {
  function1: () => {
    item.a = 3
  },
  function2: () => {
    item.b = 4
  }
}
```

Note the question marks before the column inside the interface, this is to tell that these properties are optional. If you don't set these question marks, typescript will think these are obligatory, so it will emit an error if you create `item` and don't declare `a` and `b` properties

Comment: thank you Alex, i'didn't know that in an interface i can also use function as type. Very useful and well written comment!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to denote item `object` as `any`.

To accomplish a desired consistency an interface could be defined as follows

```
interface ItemObject {
    [key: string]: any
}

var item: ItemObject= {};
```

to make compact:

```
var item: {[k: string]: any} = {};
```

now item can accept any string as key and any type as value